# Hidding column based on click event in Slickgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

I am trying to update someones code. what I try to do is hide a column based on a NAV bar that is pressed.
he is working with slickgrid. so I have this Nav bar button :

```
  "items": [
        {
            "label": "Rekken",
            "value": "Rek"
        },
```

when Clicked on this I Want to hide a Specific column :

```
{
"id": 13,
"name": "Fabricant",
"field": "J",
"maxWidth": 100,
"editor": "editors.texteditor",
"autofilter": true
```

},

what I have now is this function :

```
glue.link(document.querySelector("#nav"), "focus", {
            switchTab: function (e, div, att) {
                div.click();
                depFilter(att.value);
                if(att.value =="rek"){
                    // hide column based on ID
    
                }
            },
            catchAll: function (e, div, att) {
                console.log(arguments);
            }
        });
```

the if statement seems to work , I mean it is responding when I click the nav button with value 'rek' :

```
 if(att.value =="rek"){
                        // hide column based on ID
        
                    }
```

But I can't seem to target the column that I am trying to hide. anyone can give me A hint on how to do this ?

PS: the column and nav are stored in a database in json format.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Going with just DOM elements is not the way to go (you'll have much more problems now and later), what you'll need to do is call the proper SlickGrid functions to get to what you want. Most probably something like `grid.setColumns(visibleColumns);`

Comment: just a note in additional to @ghiscoding 's comment. You can't turn columns on and off as such, you have to remove the column from or add it to the columns list and use ```setColumns```. It's good to maintain the full columns array in your code and then copy it, remove invisible  columns and then pass it to ```setColumns```.